# Can articles be trialled before purchasing?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

It has been mentioned several times now on the blog:

https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/09/28/migration-wiki-documentation-articles/?cb=1

Is there any method to allow for say a 30 day trial of articles?  I don't want to invest my money in it if it doesn't do what I am looking for.  Want to replace confluence but cannot replace it if I cannot for instance "upload documents".

Can anyone from the SO/SE team please respond since no one responds to the blog entries?

Comment: Maybe it's a hint :)

Comment: And you have a [business or enterprise account](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/features/articles)?

Comment: Everything I've looked at seems to indicate it's just a new feature for business/enterprise accounts, what makes you think you'd have to pay for them on top of that?

Comment: @Nick I have a basic tier teams account that doesn't come with Articles. I have to upgrade to Business to unlock that. I assume the OP has something similar. I have the same question. I'm not going to upgrade to a higher tier  only to find the feature  not useful.

Comment: @rene So when they say they want to trial articles, they mean they want to trial Business account(+) features, that makes a whole lot more sense.

Comment: Isn't "Articles" a proper noun?

Answer (score 3):

We currently don't offer a free trial of our Business tier, but we can schedule a short demo to show you how Articles works. We're also going to soon release an interactive demo where you can try it for yourself without creating a brand new Teams instance.

Comment: Can you tell us if i can attach an email or a document to an article?

Comment: We do not support attachments at this time.

Comment: we cannot move to articles unless this is brought in just an FYI.  Many customers rely on individual attachments as much as people hate having them.