# Plans and pricing of Stack Overflow for Teams

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

There are four [plans](https://stackoverflow.co/teams/pricing) available for Stack Overflow for Teams: Free, Basic, Business, and Enterprise. Is there any way to use the trial version of the Basic and Business plans?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the free version to try out most features, but according to [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401651/can-articles-be-trialled-before-purchasing/401670#401670) by a staff member

> We currently don't offer a free trial of our Business tier, but we can schedule a short demo...

Since the Basic and Business versions are a few dollars per month, why not just pay for a month or two as your trial and then cancel if it's not for you.

Comment: I'd also suspect unless you needed the integrations or articles, the basic or free versions would be good enough to proof of concept things for a small number of users.